# sh.ErrorReturnCOde_2 error when using buildozer after adding pandas as requirement

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

```
[[INFO]:    Building liblzma for arm64-v8a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/d/seaborn/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/liblzma/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/liblzma
[DEBUG]:   -> running autoreconf -vif
[DEBUG]:        autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
[DEBUG]:        autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
[DEBUG]:        autoreconf: running: autopoint --force
[DEBUG]:        Can't exec "autopoint": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 293.
[DEBUG]:        autoreconf: error: autopoint failed with exit status: 2
Exception in thread background thread for pid 20841:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/rock/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rock/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/rock/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/rock/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2:
```

I have set the p4b to develop mode and added all the requirements which i got from pipdeptree as you can see in `buildozer.spec`below:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you forgot to include your spec file?